# Nullable generic property

Tags: c#, generics

Why can't I fill the default generic property with the value null if the property is nullable and the generic type is not restricted in any way?

```
public class Class_0<TValue> where TValue : struct
{
    public TValue? Value { get; } = null; // is valid
}

public class Class_1<TValue> where TValue : class
{
    public TValue? Value { get; } = null; // is valid
}

public class Class_2<TValue>
{
    public TValue? Value { get; } = null;  // error
}
```

I need the property to be able to be either struct or class and always be filled with the value null. I can't write something like this: `where TValue : struct, class`.

Comment: What error do you get? I suspect it's only something like "Do not initialize values to their defaults", which is just a code-style warning.

Comment: @PMF "Cannot convert 'null' to type parameter 'TValue' because it could be a value type. Consider using 'default(T)' instead"

Comment: @PMF But if you put the default - `public TValue? Value { get; } = default;` then `new Class_2<int>()` will write null value 0 instead of null to the nullable property.

Comment: It's not as easy as I thought, sorry. It seems it's not possible to have a generic property that can both be a nullable value type and a reference type at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because of a leaky abstraction. The C# compiler's convenient `?` syntax hides the fact that the types `TValue? where TValue : class` and `TValue? where TValue : struct` are incompatible CLR types. The first one is just `TValue`: the nullable annotation on reference types is not part of the CLR type system and is implemented as a bunch of attributes the compiler is aware of. The second one is the generic value type `Nullable<TValue>`. Given a single declaration like your `Class_2<TValue>`, the compiler cannot emit a CLR generic type declaration that would behave like both, because `TValue?` would need to be represented as `!0` in the first case and `` System.Nullable`1<!0> `` in the second (the IL syntax `!0` refers to the first generic argument of the active generic type context, in this case `` Class_2`1 ``). So what does the compiler do? If you open your example in ILDasm, you will see that

```cs
public class Class_2<TValue>
{
    public TValue? Value { get; }
}
```

compiles to the generic type `` Class_2`1<TValue> `` with a property and a backing field of type `TValue` without any nullability annotations, i.e. the compiler just gives up and ignores the `?` (I am using .NET 8). This may not be the ideal way of dealing with the situation, but it is the only one that provides backward compatibility. And unfortunately this means that you cannot write a single C# generic that would do what you want: you will have to have separate declarations for reference and value type arguments, or give up on built-in nullability and implement it manually.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Another problem with the proposed way (besides implementation duplication) is that c# doesn't allow overloading classes and methods by a generic type, which means I can't have 2 identical entry points for my logic (two classes with the same names but generic delimited - one for structures, one for classes).

Comment: Right. It's annoying but there is nothing we can do. Entry points have to stay separate if you want them to use language-native nullability constructs. But you can often put your core logic into a common generic base class with only a little overhead, using something like `internal readonly record struct MyNullable<T> (T Value, bool HasValue)` if your core logic needs to pass around the value rather than just the null/non-null tag.

Answer (score 3):

I would do that:

```
public class Class_2<TValue>
{
    public TValue Value { get; } = default!;
}
```

And then using it like that:

```
var o = Class_2<int?>();
var o = Class_2<int>();

var o = Class_2<object?>();
var o = Class_2<object>();
```

The reason is in dotnet refrence types (`string`, `object`,..) are nullable. Adding the question mark at the end (`string?`, `object?`,..) doesn't change their type. It just tell the IDE to remind you to check for nullabity.

```
public class Class_1<TValue> where TValue : class
{
    public TValue? Value { get; } = null;
}
```

On the other hand adding a question mark on struct types (`int`, `long`,..)  change their type to (`Nullable<int>`, `Nullable<long>`).

```
public class Class_0<TValue> where TValue : struct
{
    public TValue? Value { get; } = null;
    public Nullable<TValue> SameAs { get; } = null;
}
```

In the last implementation when you declare a generic type parameter without any constraints, it is implicitly assumed to have the "class" constraint. This is why the `default` keyword was equivalent `0` and `null` was not accepted.

```
public class Class_2<TValue>
{
    public TValue? Value { get; } = null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But putting the responsibility for wrapping the value in nullable on the consumer of the class doesn't suit me.

Answer (score 0):

I think this achieves what you want. It accepts either a struct or a class as the generic type, and the compiler enforces nullability only where necessary.

**(bear with me and ignore the `T?` for now)**

### Solution

```cs
public class GenericClass<T>
{
    public T? Value { get; } = default;
}
```

### Validation

The compiler correctly hints to you whether to expect a nullable object back, or whether it's a non-nullable struct. Try each of the following, and notice what it initialises `Value` to:

```cs
var withNonNullableString = new GenericClass<string>(); // Value: null (caution!)
var withNullableString = new GenericClass<string?>(); // Value: null
var withNonNullableInt = new GenericClass<int>(); // Value: 0
var withNullableInt = new GenericClass<int?>(); // Value: null
```

Now, about the `T?` when using a struct. If you try this in a compiler, you'll note that the `withNonNullableInt` *knows* that `withNonNullableInt.Value` isn't nullable. Which is pretty smart.

So, I think it's achieving what you want. A generic class that behaves using the correct null / non-null semantics, depending if you pass it a class or a struct as the generic type.

### Couple of things to be aware of

- I put "caution!" above, because when using a non-nullable `string` as the generic type, `Value` will still be nullable. It's OK though; the compiler does correctly warns you that the `.Value` is in fact nullable.
- This is all assuming you've got nullable type enabled.